How to move a vertex parallel to camera view
i would like to know if there is a way in Blender to move vertices in the plane parallel to the active camera. or if i need a plugin for this purpose.
for context, i'm modelling an object from reference images with perspective and this feature would help a lot.

You need to change your Transform orientation to View, it also has a , (comma) shortcut.
